# LINQ query to parse List and get multiple groups based on the initial character

Tags: c#, linq

Greeting Gurus, I have a LINQ query that parses a text file.

```
var p = from n in File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\data.txt")
                            where n.StartsWith("-"||"/")
select n;
```

I'm getting an error about the or operator `||` cannot be applied to strings?!
I'm trying to get groups of lines that start with different switches (a group for `/` and a group for `-`.

Comment: `StartsWith` acctepting regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
IEnumerable<string> p =
    from n in File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\data.txt")
    where n.StartsWith("-") || n.StartsWith("/")
    select n;
```

If you want to also group by the first character, then try this:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<char, string>> p =
    from n in File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\data.txt")
    where n.Length > 1
    let k = n[0]
    where k == '-' || k == '/'
    group n by k;
```

Perhaps you need this:

```
ILookup<char, string> p =
    File
        .ReadAllLines(@"D:\data.txt")
        .Where(n => n.Length > 1 && (n[0] == '-' || n[0] == '/'))
        .ToLookup(n => n[0], x => x);
    
IEnumerable<string> startsWithHyphen = p['-'];
IEnumerable<string> startsWithSlash = p['/'];
```

Comment: That helped a lot. One more question. How can I group the lines based on the same characters instead of stuffing all the matches into the same collection.

Comment: Please explain what "group the lines based on the same characters" and "stuffing all the matches into the same collection" means?

Comment: Excellent, that helped a lot with the grouping.

Comment: I really love LINQ, any recommendations for learning it better?

Comment: I recommend you answer the questions that people trying to help you ask.

Comment: Do other languages have anything comparable to LINQ or better?

Comment: @user937036 - Yes. A lot of languages have comparable features. It depends if you mean the language integrated query part of the framework for querying lists of zero or more values. The two are related but distinct.

Comment: I mean Language integrated query in other languages that's as powerful as linq.